# Load Text File into DataFrame with Specific Format

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to load a text file with the following format:

```
PR  Maybe   IMPACT  TASK    FIST    
12  SA              1450    1       
12  RE                  0
```

I tried something like this but the formatting of the text file is weird.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"file.TXT",sep = "    ", delimiter = "\t")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.read_fwf` instead if you are using a fixed-width file. [Reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html)